# Spritekit get back to rootViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I am currently learning with SpriteKit. I have a background music player instance at main ViewController. However, when I tried to access back to it from SKScene class, I cannot stop/change the player.

```
ViewController *vc = (ViewController *) self.view.window.rootViewController;
AVAudioPlayer *player = vc.backgroundMusicPlayer;
[player stop]; //nothing happened
```

I am new to iOS dev, what is the way for managing SpriteKit background music player? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a background music player singleton, e.g.

**BackgroundMusicPlayer.h**

```
@interface BackgroundMusicPlayer : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedPlayer;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

@end
```

**BackgroundMusicPlayer.m**

```
@implementation BackgroundMusicPlayer

+ (instancetype)sharedPlayer
{
    static BackgroundMusicPlayer *sharedPlayer;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedPlayer = [self new];
    });
    return sharedPlayer;
}

@end
```

Then you can access your audio player from anywhere by calling `[[BackgroundMusicPlayer sharedPlayer] audioPlayer]`.

Comment: I never thought of this! Thanks for your prompt reply! :)

Comment: Strangely the audio will only play when within ViewController as an property. I think it's my codes somewhere error, anyway, I get your idea and thanks again.

Comment: You probably have a memory management error. I've made this mistake in the past, where I release the `AVAudioPlayer` object thinking it will release itself.

Comment: I have notice that the sharedPlayer returning null with `sharedPlayer = [self new];`. I modified with `sharedPlayer = [[self alloc] init];` and adding the `init` method. Now it work as I want. Thanks :)

Comment: Interesting. `[self new]` is just a shortcut for `[[self alloc] init]`. I wonder what's happening there...